# What mind was in Jesus that the Philippians were advised to also have?

Tags: philippians

Philippians 2:5 ASV

Have this mind in you, which was also in Christ Jesus:

Comment: It is not clear what is being asked. 'What mind' can mean (in the English language) 'What physical (or metaphysical) _structure_ ?' - which may be termed 'mind'. Or 'what mind' can mean 'how was that person minded ?' What were they minded to do ? Dealing with this specific text in an hermeneutic manner requires this distinction to be realised and administrated.

Comment: @NigelJ. You make difficulty when there is none, render vague the plain language of scripture. Does the verse cited has any hint of metaphysical structure? You may answer the question in an hermeneutic manner to address the questions in your comment here.

Comment: The question is about the English translation, not the original Greek.

Comment: @NigelJ. What does the original greek and the English translation show? Do they show metaphysical structure? Do they show how was the person Jesus was minded? You can include all those in your answer.

Comment: I have up-voted the answer which shows that the 'mind' is explained in the rest of the sentence . . . . .  unless you are asking about what 'mind' means in a metaphysical sense.

Comment: @NigelJ. Thank you for the vote. I am not asking about what "mind" in the metaphysical sense, but you are free to answer the Q if you think that metaphysical sense is hinted in this verse.

Comment: Don't the following verses make it extremely obvious what Paul meant? I don't understand how this is a question.

Comment: @curiousdannii. The question is designed to establish what mind did Jesus had?  Those that say he had the mind of the almighty can justify their answer here. Same for those that don't. The bible is addressed to our reason and understanding. We interpret it using these faculties. By interpreting the scripture with the assumption of a hypothesis that is not there, the principles of reason and understanding are violated. Are we to surrender reason in interpreting and trying to understand the bible?

Comment: If you want the question to do all of that you need to edit it to actually ask it. What you've written only looks like a trivial question that could only be asked by someone who deliberately refused to read the following verses, and that's not the sort of content we want on this site.

Comment: @curiousdannii. All verses should be examined based on what the whole bible anyway. Anybody can answer whatever their understanding of the verse is. The issue seems to be with those whose understanding is challenged by the q. What kind of understanding is that that can't stand reasonable scrutiny and resorts to closing the q instead of answering the question. If I say 1=1 and you say 1=2, it's obvious that you are the one who need to clarify why 1=2? The value of 1=1 is true.  Changing the meaning of words or numbers to accommodate an assertion doesn't make it true. That is duplicity.

Comment: I have no idea what you're going on about. No one has said anything like 1=2. All I said was that your question looks trivial, so if you think there's something interesting to ask about here it's your job to edit your question to explain.

Comment: @curiousdannii..How many mind do you think Jesus has. If you say 1 human mind, you answer according to that point, if you say he has 2 minds living in 1 person, you answer according to that assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't "this mind" being explained in the rest of the sentence, all the way down to "death on a cross" in v8. Surely the point of the sentence is to describe the kind of mind Christ had, as demonstrated by his conduct.

In which case, the key points would be "emptied himself" and "humbled himself".

At the same time, coming in from the other side, the sentence is continuing the thought of vv3-4. It explains how we can avoid acting "from selfishness or conceit" and acting in our own interest. It continues the advice that we should count others better than ourselves and act in the interests of others.

So I suggest that the kind of mind which "counts others better than oneself and acts in the interests of others" is being offered as resembling "the mind of Christ".

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question about "the mind of Christ" in Phil 2:5 given explicitly in the previous verses with the ultimate example in the following  verses.  Let me set this out to show this more clearly:

**The Principle:**

> **2**. make my joy complete by being **like-minded**, having the same love, being united in spirit and purpose.

**More Specifically:**

> **3** Do nothing out of selfish ambition or empty pride, but in **humility** consider others more important than yourselves. **4** Each of
> you should look not only to your own interests, but also to the
> interests of **others**.

**The Great Exemplar = Christ**

> **5** Let this **mind** be in you which was also in Christ Jesus:

**More specifically:**

> **6** Who, existing in the form of God, did not consider equality with God something to be exploited [BSB] **7** but emptied Himself, taking
> the form of a servant, being made in human likeness. **8** And being
> found in appearance as a man, He humbled Himself and became obedient
> to death— even death on a cross.

**In Summary**

Paul encourages Christ's followers to be loving and others-centered.  This the same "mind-set" of Christ, who, despite being in the form of God, humbled Himself in the ultimate way to serve others.

That is the "mind" of Christ; to be humble and consider other more important than yourselves.

Answer (score 0):

The word in Greek translated as *have* [in] *mind* is φρονέω (*phroneō*).  It is closely related to φρόνιμος (*phronimos*), which is sometimes translated *wise* or *prudent*.

The question should maybe be, "What was *this* that the Philippians were to have kept in mind?" The answer would be all that was enumerated above: have the *same love* as Christ, be of *one mind*, *let nothing be done through strife or vainglory but in lowliness*, let each esteem each *other better than themselves*, look not on ones *own things* but the *things of others* (v.2-4).  These were all the things that Christ kept in mind.

Theophylact writes:

> *Let this mind be in you, which was also in Christ Jesus*. That is to say, just as Christ humbled Himself and became a servant for our sake,
> so also should we imitate His humility and become servants to one
> another. For it is only by humility that we can overcome the pride and
> selfishness that separate us from each other and from God. Let us
> therefore follow the example of Christ and seek to serve others rather
> than seeking to be served ourselves (*PG* 125:393).

Answer (score 0):

The Apostle Paul explains it quite nicely at Philippians 2:3-8. Vs3, "Do nothing from selfishness or empty conceit, but with humility of mind let each of your regard one another as more important than himself; vs4, do not merely look out for your own personal interests, but also for the interest of others."

Vs5, Have this attitude in yourselves which was also in Christ Jesus." So what kind of an attitude and love did Jesus have? Vs6, who, although (although means in spite of the fact) He/Jesus existed in the form of God, did not regard equality with God a thing to be grasped."

vs7, but emptied Himself, (how?) by taking the form of a bond-servant, and being made in the likeness of men. vs8, And being found in appearance as a man, He humbled Himself by becoming obedient to the point of death, even death on a cross."

So what Jesus Christ did was go from one form as God and took on another form of a bond-servant/man. Instead of clinging to what was rightfully His before He became a man He forewent the prerogatives of His deity.

So, the point is that Jesus Christ, (even though He was God in flesh) strictly and only thought of others by dying on that cross for the world. It is also important to note that what He did was voluntary.

While verses 5-11 contain some of the most important Christological truths in the Bible, they were written in a context which should encourage Christians to emulate the example of Christ in humility. Thus, having the mind of Christ means, "to think as Christ thought."

I want to make one more observation that is important as it relates to Philippians 2:12, "So then by beloved, just as you have always obeyed, not as in my presence only, but now much more in my absence, work out you salvation with fear and trembling."

This verse is "NOT" teaching to work out your salvation to get saved or to stay saved. The Apostle Paul is saying, to work out the deliverance/solution of your problems. Why? Vs13, "Because it is God who is at work in you, both to will and to work for His good pleasure." Vs14, "Do all things without grumbling or disputing."

This verse is referring back to verses 2-4 which is the reason the Apostle Paul is writing.

Answer (score 0):

(*This is related to my answer to the very recent question, [If Jesus has never sinned and has never done any wrong, why did he tell the The Rich Young Ruler that He is not Good and that God alone is good? - Christianity Stack Exchange](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/95296/if-jesus-has-never-sinned-and-has-never-done-any-wrong-why-did-he-tell-the-the/95298#95298).*)

Paul is saying that he has the same mindset that Jesus had, and that *all* Christians can and should think the same way:

> Fulfil ye my joy, that ye be likeminded, having the same love, being of one accord, of one mind.
> Let nothing be done through strife or vainglory; but in lowliness of mind let each esteem other better than themselves.
> — Philippians 2:2–3

In becoming human, Jesus gave up his divinity, and was fully capable of sinning.
But he was in communication with God through holy spirit, which guided and advised him.
This spiritual connection enabled him to resist temptation and to have loving thoughts for all.
Throughout his entire life, including a few moments just before his death when the connection was withdrawn, Jesus never sinned.

> Let this mind be in you, which was also in Christ Jesus:
> Who, being in the form of God, thought it not robbery to be equal with God:
> But made himself of no reputation, and took upon him the form of a servant, and was made in the likeness of men:
> And being found in fashion as a man, he humbled himself, and became obedient unto death … .
> — Philippians 2:6–8

The NLT has 2:7 as "*… he gave up his divine privileges; he took the humble position of a slave and was born as a human being …*".

But all baptised and converted Christians have this same spiritual connection with God that Jesus had experienced since birth; they only need to exercise it to develop personal characters that are just like Jesus's, always obedient to God, personally humble, and loving and forgiving toward those that aren't.

> For it is God which worketh in you both to will and to do of his good pleasure.
> Do all things without murmurings and disputings:
> That ye may be blameless and harmless, the sons of God, without rebuke, in the midst of a crooked and perverse nation, among whom ye shine as lights in the world
> — Philippians 2:13–15

It is God's nature or character that Jesus was filled with.
He had the *mind* of God in the *body* of a human.
It is up to Christians to develop their minds to be like that of God, which is what Philippians 2:5 is talking about.

Comment: How did you determine that Christ laid aside His divinity? The verse does not specifically say what Jesus Christ "emptied" Himself of. Since He is God in the first place according to Philippians 2:6, how can He become not God? Besides, Colossians 2:9 states, "For in Him all the FULNESS of Deity dwells in bodily form." Also according to John 17:5, Jesus requested to be glorified with the glory He already had before the word was."  What makes sense is that when Jesus Christ incarnated as a man (vs8) He did not take advantage of the prerogatives He already had in the first place.

Comment: I agree with @Mr.Bond. 'In him the fulness of deity dwells, bodily' - showing the subsistence of both deity and humanity in one Person.

Comment: @Mr.Bond, Ephesians 3:19 says Christians are "*filled with all the fulness of God*",
and 4:13 refers to the "*fullness of Christ*".
Does that mean that Christians *are* God or *are* Christ, and that while physical humans they *are* fully divine? I don't think so.

Comment: @Mr.Bond. God wasn't playing a game with humanity. What example would Jesus have set if he only pretended to be human? He had to live and die as a human, yet remain sinless *without* having any inherent divine power that isn't available to everyone else. He had to prove that with God's help humans *can* resist sin. Jesus did not say: "You must follow my example and strive to live the perfect life that I was able to live as a physical human. Oh, and don't tell anyone, but I actually cheated.". Jesus had to actually risk his eternal life. If not, what point was there to making a mock sacrifice?

Comment: @Ray Your reading into those verses you quoted. Paul's point is for them to know the love of Jesus Christ to the fullest extent possible. Vs19, "and to know the love of Christ which surpasses knowledge, that you "MAY" be filled up to all the fulness of God." At 4:11-13 Paul  God has called full-time, occupational ministers to help believers MATURE in the Lord, or to become more and more like Christ Himself to the fulness measure. Please, read the context in order to understand the points of what Scripture is teaching.

Comment: @Mr.Bond, the CSB has "*For the entire fullness of God’s nature dwells bodily [fn: Or nature lives in a human body] in Christ,*". It is God's nature or character that Jesus was filled with. He had the *mind* of God in the *body* of a human. It is up to Christians to develop their minds to be like that of God, which is what Philippians 2:5 is talking about.